# Generating Unique Number for Large Scale System

Tags: math, random, e-commerce, id-generation, purchase-order

Most of us have seen that when we make purchase from Amazon like sites we get a Order Number or Purchase Number(of 10-12 digits) which looks like some random number. Similarly I want generate unique ids for large scale system. What is the best algorithm to generate it?

Some methods which I thought are not efficient or not applicable to large scale system

```
1) Generating string using rand function ( Array.new(12){rand(10)}.join) and checking 
   whole table whether it is exists. It is time consuming, inefficient and may struck 
   in infinite loop.
2) Using time-stamp - I think this cannot be used for large scale system because large
   no. user can excess system at same time.
3) Combination of 1) & 2) also creates issue as second when it generates same 1)   
Auto increment : I don't want to use.
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use autoincrement?

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason why a normal [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) won't work? It will produce a longer id, but it's simple, it works, and most languages have generation code built in.

Comment: Do you think amazon uses UUID?

Comment: @clickit I doubt it since the lengths are completely different and UUIDs are hex.

Answer (score 0):

there must be some kind of database involved in this large scale system, so add an auto-incrementing integer to your database.  Dish out these unique integers without
worry if some are never used.